# Convert ctypes Struct to bytearray in python

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

Is there a way to convert a Ctypes Structure including a pointer to a bytearray?

```
class SRamAccess(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('channel', ctypes.c_uint), ('offset', ctypes.c_uint), ('len', ctypes.c_uint), ('data', ctypes.c_char_p)]
```

Comment: You need the pointer contents as well?

Answer (score 10):

Just pass it to `bytearray()`:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> class SRamAccess(ctypes.Structure):
...  _fields_ = [('channel', ctypes.c_uint), ('offset', ctypes.c_uint), ('len', ctypes.c_uint), ('data', ctypes.c_char_p)]
...
>>> s = SRamAccess(1,2,3,b'blah')
>>> bytearray(s)
bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0 .\x1a\xed\x01\x00\x00')
#           \______________/\______________/\______________/\______________/\________________________/
#                   1               2               3         padding          pointer64
```

Note that 'blah' is not part of the structure.  The last 8 bytes (64-bit Python) are the pointer address, and the 4 bytes before that are padding to align the 8-byte pointer to an 8-byte offset in the structure.

You would need an array in the structure to see array contents:

```
>>> class SRamAccess(ctypes.Structure):
...  _fields_ = [('channel', ctypes.c_uint), ('offset', ctypes.c_uint), ('len', ctypes.c_uint), ('data', ctypes.c_char * 5)]
...
>>> s = SRamAccess(1,2,3,b'blah')
>>> bytearray(s)
bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00blah\x00\x00\x00\x00')
#           \______________/\______________/\______________/\______/\__________/
#                   1               2               3         blah    padding
```

Note that last 3 bytes are padding to make the whole structure a multiple of 4 bytes in size so an array of such structures keeps the 4-byte integers aligned on 4-byte boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

One way would be to create a helper method that does the conversion. Below is such an example, which also does the conversion back (as I imagine that converting one way only would be pretty much useless).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct


class SRamAccess(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("channel", ct.c_uint),
        ("offset", ct.c_uint),
        ("len", ct.c_uint),
        ("data", ct.c_char_p),
    ]

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, buf):
        inst = cls.from_buffer(buf)
        return inst

    def serialize(self):
        struct_size = ct.sizeof(SRamAccess)
        size = struct_size + self.len
        buf = (ct.c_char * size)()
        ct.memmove(ct.addressof(buf), ct.addressof(self), struct_size)
        ct.memmove(ct.addressof(buf) + struct_size, self.data, self.len)
        return bytearray(buf)

    def __str__(self):
        s = self.__repr__()
        for field_name, _ in self._fields_[:-1]:
            s += "\n  {0:s}: {1:}".format(field_name, getattr(self, field_name))
        s += "\n  {0:s}:".format(self._fields_[-1][0])
        for i in range(self.len):
            s += " 0x{0:02X}".format(self.data[i])
        return "{0:s}\n".format(s)


def main(*argv):
    text = b"abcd1234"
    ssrc = SRamAccess(1, 2, len(text), text)
    print("Src:", ssrc)
    buf = ssrc.serialize()
    print("Buf:", buf)
    sdst = SRamAccess.deserialize(buf)
    print("\nDst:", sdst)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q060926139>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Src: <__main__.SRamAccess object at 0x00000298F25553C8>
>   channel: 1
>   offset: 2
>   len: 8
>   data: 0x61 0x62 0x63 0x64 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34
>
> Buf: bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \xc6V\xf2\x98\x02\x00\x00abcd1234')
>
> Dst: <__main__.SRamAccess object at 0x00000298F2555448>
>   channel: 1
>   offset: 2
>   len: 8
>   data: 0x61 0x62 0x63 0x64 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34
>
>
> Done.
> ```

As a note, this representation is also storing the last field (pointer) address which is irrelevant (as the contents is also stored).

---

#### Update *#0*

Previous variant doesn't behave well when there are ***NUL* (*0*, *\x00*) *char*s in the string** (`text = b"abcd\x001234"`), because ***ctypes.c_char_p* is used for *NUL* terminated strings**. I think that the *len* field presence automatically implies the above scenario.

*code01.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct
import struct


CharPtr = ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)


class SRamAccess(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("channel", ct.c_uint),
        ("offset", ct.c_uint),
        ("len", ct.c_uint),
        ("data", CharPtr),
    ]

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, buf):
        fmt_prefix = "II"
        data_len = len(buf) - struct.calcsize(fmt_prefix)
        fmt = fmt_prefix + "b" * data_len
        unpacked = struct.unpack(fmt, buf)
        return cls(unpacked[0], unpacked[1], 0, unpacked[2:])

    def serialize(self):
        buf = struct.pack("II" + "b" * self.len, self.channel, self.offset, *self.data[:self.len])
        return bytearray(buf)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == "data":
            self.len = len(value)
            buf = (ct.c_char * len(value))(*value)
            super().__setattr__(name, buf)
        else:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)

    def __str__(self):
        s = self.__repr__()
        for field_name, _ in self._fields_[:-1]:
            s += "\n  {0:s}: {1:}".format(field_name, getattr(self, field_name))
        s += "\n  {0:s}:".format(self._fields_[-1][0])
        for i in range(self.len):
            s += " 0x{0:02X}".format(ord(self.data[i]))
        return "{0:s}\n".format(s)


def main(*argv):
    text = b"abcd\x00123"
    ssrc = SRamAccess(1, 2, 12345, text)
    print("Src:", ssrc)
    buf = ssrc.serialize()
    print("Buf:", buf)
    sdst = SRamAccess.deserialize(buf)
    print("\nDst:", sdst)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q060926139>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code01.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> Src: <__main__.SRamAccess object at 0x0000025277C85348>
>   channel: 1
>   offset: 2
>   len: 8
>   data: 0x61 0x62 0x63 0x64 0x00 0x31 0x32 0x33
>
> Buf: bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00abcd\x00123')
>
> Dst: <__main__.SRamAccess object at 0x0000025277C85448>
>   channel: 1
>   offset: 2
>   len: 8
>   data: 0x61 0x62 0x63 0x64 0x00 0x31 0x32 0x33
>
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes** (changes from the previous version):

- Handles *NUL* *char*s
- Uses [[Python 3.Docs]: struct - Interpret strings as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#module-struct) to do the conversions
- *len* is automatically computed from the data passed as argument (in *__setattr__*). Note that setting it afterwards might yield unpredicted results

  - Code is more complex
  - Buffer is smaller (no irrelevant data serialized)